# Send email with attachment from any email program

Tags: email, ms-access, email-attachments

I need to send an email from an MS Access database with an attachment (**not an Access object**, but a separate file), but not tied to any one email software (Groupwise, Outlook, etc). I have found code to send an email with an attachment using Groupwise and Outlook, and there is the generic `DoCmd.SendObject` which only appears to support attaching Access objects. Is there a way to send an email from Access with an attachment, regardless of the email client configured on the user's PC?

**Rationale:** There's complications with software rollout here. The machine I work on has Access 2013 and Outlook 2013 installed. The users of the database are running Access 2010, but when I compile the database into a .accde in 2013, it does not work on 2010. The only way I can get it to work is to compile it on a much older PC also running Access 2010. However, this old PC does not have Outlook and IT won't/can't install Outlook on it. This means I can't compile the database using the Outlook library, as there is no Outlook library on the machine.

Answer (score 2):

Here is code I use to send e-mails using Gmail:

```
Public Function SendEmailViaGmail(SendTo As String, Optional Subject As String = "", Optional TextBody As String = "", Optional ReplyTo As String = "", Optional AttachedFiles As Variant = "") As String
On Error GoTo send_emailErr
    Dim ErrNum As Long
    Dim ErrDes As String
    SendEmailViaGmail = ""
    ErrNum = 0
    Set cdomsg = CreateObject("CDO.message")
    With cdomsg.Configuration.Fields
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2   'NTLM method
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smptserverport") = 587
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = sendusername '
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = sendpassword
        .Update
    End With
    ' build email parts
    With cdomsg
        .To = SendTo
        .FROM = sendusername 
        .Subject = Subject
        .TextBody = TextBody & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "--" & vbCrLf & "Sent using Marlan Data-Systems"
        If IsArray(AttachedFiles) Then
            For Each AttachedFile In AttachedFiles
                If Len(AttachedFile) > 3 Then .AddAttachment AttachedFile
            Next
        Else
            If Len(AttachedFiles) > 3 Then .AddAttachment AttachedFiles
        End If
        .send
    End With
    SendEmailViaGmail = "Done!"
send_emailExit:
    Set cdomsg = Nothing
    Exit Function

send_emailErr:
    ErrNum = Err.Number
    ErrDes = Err.Description
    Select Case Err.Number

    Case -2147220977  'Likely cause, Incorrectly Formatted Email Address, server rejected the Email Format
        SendEmailViaGmail = "Please Format the Email Address Correctly."

    Case -2147220980  'Likely cause, No Recipient Provided (No Email Address)
        SendEmailViaGmail = "Please Provide an Email Address"

    Case -2147220960 'Likely cause, SendUsing Configuration Error
    SendEmailViaGmail = "SendUsing Configuration Error"

    Case -2147220973  'Likely cause, No Internet Connection
        SendEmailViaGmail = "Please Check Internet Connection"

    Case -2147220975  'Likely cause, Incorrect Password
        SendEmailViaGmail = "Please Check Password"

    Case Else   'Report Other Errors
        SendEmailViaGmail = ""
    End Select
    SendEmailViaGmail = SendEmailViaGmail & " Error number: " & Err.Number & " Description: " & Err.Description
    'If ErrNum = -2147220975 Then
    '    cdomsg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smptserverport") = 465
    '    Resume
    'End If
    Resume send_emailExit
End Function
```

`AttachedFiles` is a String, or an Array of Strings, representing full paths to file or files that are to be attached to the email.
*CDO.message* is a Microsoft windows object.
You can replace value of `smtpserver` to some other mailing service. If you do so, please be sure to modify other parameters as well.
Code is based on code I found on the web.